Code doesn't run all elements when applied to button - does when run manually
I have code that allows me to save my worksheet as a PDF, save it to a folder, and also attach it to an email.
within the code I have a "Call" to run DeleteSomeFormulas which removes any formulas within a given range, leaving the data in place.
The code runs perfectly if I run this manually from the Developer tab, but if I apply it to a button it does everything it should except for the removal of formulas.
Sub Email_PDF()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call DeleteSomeFormulas
Dim Path As String, File As String
Path = "Z:\Team\Staff Communications\Staff Briefings\Staff Briefings 2024" & "\"
With ActiveWorkbook: File = Left(.Name, InStr(.Name, ".") - 1): End With
With ActiveSheet
    File = "QF28 - Staff Information - Weekly Briefing week commencing " & .Name
    With .PageSetup
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = False
    End With
    .Range("A1:F110").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Path & File
End With
With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
    .Display
    .To = "Technicians"
    .Subject = "Briefing Sheet"
    .Body = "Please find attached the latest Briefing Sheet."
    .Attachments.Add Path & File & ".pdf"
End With
End Sub

DeleteSomeFormulas is:
Sub DeleteSomeFormulas()
    With ActiveSheet
        Call fileProtection(False)
        Range("A2:F9").Copy
        Range("A2:F9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Call fileProtection(True)
    End With
End Sub

Both pieces of code run perfectly if run manually, and Email_PDF runs from a button, but the DeleteSomeFormulas does not run as a Call when run from the button.
Query also posted here

Could someone let me know what formatting i need to add to allow my code to be displayed as code within my question?

Side notes: your With ActiveSheet in DeleteSomeFormulas isn't doing anything (you're missing . before the two instances of Range), and you can bypass the clipboard using .Range("A2:F9").Value = .Range("A2:A9").Value.

side note, Application.Run may behoove you if you're executing a subroutine from another module (including running Private subroutines); seeing Call within your code, where said term is deprecated, is an unnecessary level of redundancy.

changing the code to ' Sub DeleteSomeFormulas()
Call fileProtection(False)
.Range("A2:F9").Value = .Range("A2:A9").Value
Call fileProtection(True)
End Sub' returns Compile Error, Invalid or Unqualified Reference

You left out the With

'code'Sub DeleteSomeFormulas()
With ActiveSheet
Call fileProtection(False)
.Range("A2:F9").Value = .Range("A2:A9").Value
Call fileProtection(True)
End With
End Sub '/code'  that strips out the code and does not leave the date.

DeleteSomeFormulas changed to
Sub DeleteSomeFormulas(ws As Worksheet)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call fileProtection(False)
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name
    With ws.Range("A2:F9")
     .Value2 = .Value2
     End With
    Call fileProtection(True)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

This is then called by
Call DeleteSomeFormulas(ActiveSheet)

